# Problem installing Google App Engine from MSI

Tags: google-app-engine

I downloaded Python and installed it, and when I go download GoogleAppEngine_1.2.0.msi and try to install it and I get this error:

> This installation package could not be
>   opened.  Contact the application
>   vendor to verify that this is a valid
>   Windows Installer package.

Am I forgetting something?  I am assuming this is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error.  The file downloaded by IE was about 190k and would not run.  The file ought to be 2.7M.  Firefox downloads correctly.  Also IE will download correctly if you select RUN instead of SAVE.  That is my experience and I now have the SDK installed.  I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Download it again and try to install the newly downloaded file. Maybe the file was damaged during download or not completely downloaded which can both happen sometimes.

If this does not help and the same error message appears you could control the checksum which should be

5ea87b8ed3011a5f55a9135c96abe96b6a6fd48b

for this file.

When you are sure that the downloaded file is ok, check if the version of your operating system is supported.

Maybe installing the Windows installer could help?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4

If not, try out on another machine or inside a virtual machine.

Comment: maybe installing the windows installer could help - i updated my answer

Comment: still not working - I am going to try it on my laptop, see if that might work?